# Can I obtain citizenship through my great-grandfather?

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship, children, uk-citizenship

My father is getting his citizenship through his grandfather who was born in the United Kingdom. As my dad was born in Canada, once he gets his citizenship, can I get my UK citizenship through him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your father was born outside the UK, once he gets his citizenship he will be a *UK citizen by descent*. UK citizens by descent generally cannot pass on citizenship to their children who are born outside the UK.

There is at least one exception however, in that if the UK citizen by descent lived in the UK for at least a 3 year period, they then can pass on citizenship. See http://www.wandsworth.gov.uk/info/200511/nationality_and_citizenship/1695/nationality_checking_service_ncs/5.

Comment: Always worth quoting the relevant stuff from the linked sites, just in case the links break :)

Comment: But the OP does not qualify for either of these scenarios as he does not have a grandfather who was born in the UK according to his post.

Comment: @ouflak but, according to this answer, if the father of OP gets citizenship and stays in UK for atleast 3 years then OP can get UK citizenship

Comment: Only if the OP has a grandfather who was born in the UK, which the OP has not stated is the case. *His father* qualifies through that route possibly, but not the OP.

Answer (score 2):

No. There are considerable limits to just how far back the acquistion of UK citizenship by ancestry will reach.

**Edit**: Your father qualifies to acquire UK citizenship through several possible scenarios because he had a grandparent who was born in the UK. However, unless you've described your lineage incorrectly, you do not have a grandfather who was born in the UK (it would be your great-grandfather). As such, there is no path to UK citizenship by this means according to current British nationality law.

Comment: Do you have any references to back this up? What are the limits?

Comment: @JoErNanO the requirements are clearly stated in the application form and this answer is fully correct. Please reverse the d/v and u/v like me, Hugs!

Comment: SE does require that people don't provide one-line answers, exactly as the post notice suggests....

Comment: @GayotFow I did not down vote. I'm just a fan of authoritative references. :)

Comment: @JoErNanO, it is somewhat difficult to prove the negative case as that means effectively quoting all of the British Nationality Act, and then stating that nowhere in there is a possibility of acquiring UK citizenship by means of a great grandparent.

Comment: @Mark Mayo, SE is just fine with one-line answers as long as they are correct and succinct. Indeed, some of the best (and highest voted) answers on SE are short and to the point.

Comment: @ouflak yeah I was typing fast.  Correct and succinct sure, but they should also explain their answer, otherwise it could just be hearsay / opinion. Easier to test on SO, as you can just test their code answer or whatever, but for things like citizenship or visas, it's important we get all the info as it affects people's lives.

Comment: @Mark Mayo, Fair enough and I agree. I've expanded, but I'm concerned that the 'answer' that has the most votes at the moment does not actually apply to the OP's situation. This could be really misleading.

Comment: @ouflak yep, hopefully yours moves up.  It's gotten my upvote!

Comment: @ouflak You say "there are limits". What are these limits? Is there no reference out there explaining them?

Comment: @JoErNanO, [British Nationality Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Nationality_Act_1981). Search for 'great-grandparent'. The negative result implies atleast part of the limit.

Comment: @ouflak Search for "grandparent". You get a negative result.

Comment: @JoErNanO, The possibilities for what is *not* possible are near infinite and are not specifically listed in the BNA. And I'm not going to attempt to list the infinite possibilities either. Uncles and Aunt's are also not a path. Neither are direct cousins. Neither are father/mother-in-laws (unless adopted). I could go on and on. It's pointless. If you can't accept the general statement that there are liimits, then please post your own answer with a link to some obscure government statement somewhere that says that great-grandparents are not a path to UK citizenship and I'll upvote it.